# Navigation issue on Onsen UI. How do I work around? (Onsen UI ons-navigator implementation issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, onsen-ui

**Hi, I'm facing this issue on Onsen UI. How do I work around?**

[image]

**Intro:** The following code creates an Onsen app interface that shows a `start` page. On the `start` page are two things (1) is the `dynamic-content` and (2) is the `navigation button`.

When the `start` page loads, `pageinit` event triggers and feed/populate `dynamic-content` to the start page. `navigation button` navigates to the `start` page every time.

**The intention is to:** Populate `dynamic-content` when a dynamic content becomes available *(for this example it's at instant)*. The `dynamic-content` **should be there** for as long as the `start` page exist in DOM.

**The issue:** Happens when user try to navigate to the same page. While the animation kicks in, the `pageinit` **does trigger** for the `start` page. **But the dynamic content went missing.**

*Perhaps... when navigator is trying to animate the page, it duplicate the `start` page and without the dynamic content*

> How should I work around?

Thanks for helping. ('',)V

```
<ons-sliding-menu
    var="appMenu"
    menu-page="menu.html"
    main-page="navigator.html"
    swipeable="true"
    swipe-target-width="100px"
    side="left"
    type="overlay"
    max-slide-distance="220px">

    <div id="toast">
        <div class="fly-wrapper">
            <div class="fly-card z-depth-5" style="display:none;">
                <div class="message"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</ons-sliding-menu>

<script>
    document.addEventListener("pageinit", function(e) {
      if (e.target.id == "start") {
        document.getElementById('dynamic-content').textContent = 'The start page was here';
      }
    }, false);
</script>

<ons-template id="navigator.html" style="display:none;">
    <ons-navigator var="appNav" page="start.html"></ons-navigator>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="start.html" style="display:none;">
    <ons-page id="start" class="start">
        <div id="dynamic-content"></div>
        <a class="button" ng-click="appNav.pushPage('start.html',{animation:'simpleslide'})">
            Load start again
        </a>
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="navigator.html" style="display:none;">
    <ons-page></ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

Onsen tutorial about ons-navigator:

1. http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#Pageinitevent
2. http://codepen.io/onsen/pen/IDvFJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now I use the following work code:

`<a class="trigger-pageload" app-href="start.html">Load start page</a>`

```
$(document)
.on('tap','.trigger-pageload',function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('app-href');
    if(appNav.getCurrentPage().name!=href) appNav.replacePage(href);
});
```

**SOLLUTION:**
2 key steps as follows

1. prevent same page transition.
2. use `replacePage` instead of `pushPage` (don't follow onsen tutorial/example).

> Additional step: Please update (Onsen tutorial and example).

Comment: still does not change the problem. I suspect `pushPage()` is the cause of the problem.